# Reading insert query from csv and execute on db in TALEND

Tags: talend

I have a csv file where insert queries are present.

I want to create a job to execute query against the DB.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tFileInputDelimited component to read the csv file based on your file configuration like fields & row delimiter. Connect this component to tFlowToIterate and Connect tFlowToIterate to db component (tOracleRow, tMySQLRow likewise based on your database) with iterate link.

In tFileInputDelimited, define the schema like :  Query

tFlowToIterate will iterate each Row(insert query) and convert it in key value pair and than this will pass to DB component to execute.

In DB component, ((String)globalMap.get("row3.Query"))

Hope this help

Comment: I have the csv file, which has only one insert statement, so do I require iterate. There is only two option in schema for tFileInputDelimited(builtin &repository)

Comment: Yes, you need to use iterate.

Comment: In tFileInputDelimited, select built in and edit schema and give only one column that is your query

Comment: Insert Query  already there in csv file. So how I will give the column. should I click on '+'  in 'edit schema'

Comment: Yes, click + button and add one column that is query

Comment: It will be helpful for you if you read about the tFileInputDelimited component

Comment: Thanks for the help, there is no error in the job but it's not writing to db. do I need to put "((String)globalMap.get("row3.Query"))", if yes where ? . when I place tmysql row , by default "select id, name from employee" query is coming. So somewhat confusing, sorry to bother you. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161478/discussion-between-syncdm2012-and-preetyk).

Comment: Remove the default query and start writing tFlow and ctrl + space. It will show you the column name you have defined in flow. When you select it, it will be shown like ((String)globalMap.get("row1.columnName"))